# Fancybox 1.3.x ignores width and height parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using [Fancybox 1.3.4](http://fancybox.net/api) (currently the latest) and I use the following HTML elements:

```
<a href="LARGE_URL" title="FANCY_CAPTION" rel="gallery" class="gallery-item">
  <img src="SMALL_URL"/> 
</a> 
<a> ... repeat N times... </a>
```

Then I use the following jQuery code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.gallery-item').fancybox({
        'autoDimensions': 'false',
        'width':900,
        'height':'auto',
        'cyclic': true,
        'centerOnScroll': 'false',
        'hideOnOverlayClick': true,
        'hideOnContentClick': false,
        'overlayShow': true,
        'overlayOpacity': 0.7,
        'overlayColor': '#666',
        'titleShow': true,
        'titlePosition': 'inside',
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'speedIn': 400,
        'speedOut': 200,
        'showCloseButton': true,
        'showNavArrows': true,
        'enableEscapeButton': true
    });
  });        
</script>
```

I also tried

```
    'width':'900',
```

or setting both

```
    'width':900,
    'height':600,
```

but it just does not work.

Any solutions to this?

I need the #fancybox-wrapper element in an exact size.

Answer (score 2):

try to remove quotes around false:

```
'autoDimensions': false
```

Comment: does not help... I guess that width and height can only be set for iFrame mode?

Comment: not only for iFrame mode. it will work if you set you href attribute to some page.